# a basic question on continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which is not injective and continuous. I need to find an open set in the domain which does not get mapped to an open set in the range. how ?

Comment: You want to find or you want to prove it's existance?

Comment: You can't. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces): *'This is equivalent to the condition that the preimages of the closed sets (which are the complements of the open subsets) in Y are closed in X'*.

Comment: @GitGud Read better.

Comment: @Did Here's my interpretation of the (problematic part of the) question: Suppose $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is continuous and not injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a value $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ that gets mapped to by several $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Now one of the following is certainly true: Either there is an interval $[a,b]$ in the domain where all the $x \in [a , b ]$ get mapped to $y_0$. Then we can use $(a,b)$ as the open set we're looking for.

Or there are $x_1 <  x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y_0$ and $f(x) \neq y_0$ for all $x_1 < x < x_2$. Then $f$ either takes a minimum or a maximum on $[x_1,x_2]$ which is not $y_0$ and therefore, $f( (x_1,x_2))$ will also have a maximum or minimum, so it is not open.